# nodemon is not working " '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. "

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern, nodemon

[check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3il8p.png)

PS D:\Mern projects\movie_app> npm run dev

> movie_app@1.0.0 dev
> ./node_modules/.bin/nodemon src/index.js

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS D:\Mern projects\movie_app>

Comment: can u past the package.json script section?

Comment: update   https://i.stack.imgur.com/3il8p.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, make sure it's installed

```
npm install nodemon --save-dev
```

then change your script in package.json

```
"scripts" : {
  "dev": "nodemon src/index.js",
...
}
```